# Move organization from VSTS to TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have an organization (all my projects - Only work items, no code) on Team Services (free edition). I have now started collaborating with another team who has a licensed TFS. I need to move all my projects to TFS.

Is that possible? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://vsts-bulk-editor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) utility.

Azure DevOps Migration Tools allow you to bulk edit data in Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Azure DevOps. It has many names depending on what you are trying to achieve. It can be used to:

- Migrate data from TFS to TFS
- Migrate data from TFS to Azure DevOps Services
- **Migrate data from Azure DevOps Services to TFS**
- Bulk update in TFS or Azure DevOps Services

You can also take a look at [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) tool.

There is also a [paid service](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) that can do it.